# Add labels to lines plotly

Tags: r, dplyr, graph, plotly, legend

I needed some help labeling some overlaying lines in `plotly`.

I have a dataframe that consists of the following columns:

`df$date = c("2014-09-30","2016-03-31","2016-03-31")`, etc.

`df$company = c("google", "amazon", "twitter", "twitter", "amazon", "google")`, etc.

`df$value = c(50, 60, 40, 50, 40, 60)`, etc.

All columns are the same size.

I am plotting a time series plot using `plotly` grouped by company, so I will have 3 different lines, one for `google`, one for `twitter`, one for `amazon`, but I can't figure out how to plot each line being color coded with a legend. My code for the plot is below:

```
num <- df %>% filter(Metric == "value")
num$Date <- as.Date(num$Date)
new.df <- num %>% group_by(company)
plot_ly(data=new.df) %>% add_lines(x=new.df$Date, y = new.df$value)
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

I have also tried

```
df %>% filter(Metric == "value") %>% group_by("company") %>% 
  plot_ly(df) %>% add_lines(x = df$Date, y = df$Value)
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout

# create example data
data <-
  iris %>%
  transmute(
    company = Species,
    date = seq(50) %>% as.Date(origin = "2014-09-30") %>% rep(3),
    value = Sepal.Width
  )
data
#>        company       date value
#> 1       setosa 2014-10-01   3.5
#> 2       setosa 2014-10-02   3.0
#> 3       setosa 2014-10-03   3.2
#> 4       setosa 2014-10-04   3.1
#> 5       setosa 2014-10-05   3.6

plt <-
  data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, color = company)) +
  geom_line()

ggplotly(plt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>